# Change href on unload (or location.href change)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, location-href

There are several links (and pieces of Javascript) throughout our site that contain `/2012/responses/{pathParams...}` and I now need to conditionally add to the path, if it's a webview.

```
if (isWebview) {
  // use '/2012/responses/webview/{pathParams...}'
} else {
  // use '/2012/responses/{pathParams...}'
}
```

I can handle the links by inspecting `document.links`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to handle pieces of Javascript that use `window.location = '/2012/responses/...'`.  One method is to create a function that does the window.location change and replace the window.location statements with the function.  But, is there a way to handle it as an event, so when the page is changing I could conditionally insert the `/webview` in the URL?  Browser restrictions seem to limit the `beforeunload` event to only prompting the user.

Comment: Your question implies you have lots of unrelated bits of JavaScript working separately and compensating/correcting for other bits. Why haven't you collated all of that into a single coherent function to handle URL (or `href`) updating?

Comment: @DavidThomas really has the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. I have 2 options for you:

**Option 1:**

Do a replace all to your code using ternary inline if --> *i recommend that*

sample:

> search for:
>
> ```
>     '/2012/responses/{pathParams...}'
> ```
>
> replace with:
>
> ```
>     '/2012/responses/'+((isWebView?)?'webview/':'')+'{pathParams...}'
> ```

**Option 2:**

Put the `/webView` conditionally on *server side* inside the `{pathParams...}` variable